# jQuery - Remove and group from HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a dynamic table like this:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <col width="80" span="3">
  <tr id="id-1">
    <th colspan="3" width="240">TITLE-1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val-1</td>
    <td>val-2</td>
    <td>val-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="id-1">
    <th colspan="3">TITLE-1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val-2</td>
    <td>val-2</td>
    <td>val-3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="id-2">
    <th colspan="3">TITLE-2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>val-1</td>
    <td>val-2</td>
    <td>val-2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this table is 3 TR element with same ID. i want to remove all TR except first TR.

If not is duplicate IDs nothing change with this TR.

And i need also: in TR's is 3 td's. result must be next. if value is same group this td's:

```
<tr>
    <td>val-2</td>
    <td>val-2</td>
    <td>val-3</td>
</tr>
```

result

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">val-2</td>
    <td>val-3</td>
</tr>
```

tnx

Answer (score 0):

i changed id > class

```
$(".idxx:gt(0)").remove();
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help others to understand the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did a function to parse tr's and td's. See here http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/qo4xvqjm/ :

```
var mapTable={
    _tr:function(){
        var tabletr =  $('table tr');
        var compareid = '';
        tabletr.each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if(typeof id != 'undefined'){
                if(compareid == ''){
                    compareid = id;
                }else if(compareid == id){
                    $('#'+id).next().remove();
                    $('#'+id).remove();
                }
            }
        });
    },
    _td:function(){
        tabletr =  $('table tr');
        tabletr.each(function(){
            var tdtext = {"obj":"","txt":"","count":1};
            console.log($(this).find('th').text());
            $(this).find('td').each(function(){
                var td = $(this);
                if(tdtext.txt == ''){
                    tdtext.txt = td.text();
                    tdtext.obj = td;
                }else if(tdtext.txt == td.text()){
                    tdtext.count +=1;
                    td.hide();
                    td.addClass('todelete');
                }else{
                    //before to change
                    tdtext.obj.attr('colspan',tdtext.count);
                    //
                    tdtext = {"obj":td,"txt":td.text(),"count":1};
                }
            });
            if(tdtext.count > 1){
                tdtext.obj.attr('colspan',tdtext.count);
            }
            $('.todelete').remove();
        });
    },
    init(){
        mapTable._tr();
        mapTable._td();
    }
}
```